# How to generate combinations of array values withrespect of its key values

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

How to generate combinations of array values with respect of its key values

I am having below input from a file. a string index key and array of values

```
SL  [1,3]
SW  [5,7]
PL  [11,12]
PW  [16]
```

And I am trying to generate below combination of keys and values

eg (key):

```
(SL,SW) : < 1,5 > <  1,7 > < 3,5 > < 3,7 >
(SL,PL): < 1,11 > < 1,12 > < 3,11 > < 3,12 >
(SL,PW): < 1,16 > < 3,16 >
(SW,PL): < 5,11 > < 5,12 > < 7,11 > < 7,12 >
(SW,PW): < 5,16 > < 7,16 >
(PL,PW): < 11,16 > < 12,16 >

Consider combination of three attributes:

(SL,SW,PL): < 1,5,11 > < 1,5,12 > < 1,7,11 > < 1,7,12 > < 3,5,11 > < 3,5,12 > < 3,7,11 > < 3,7,12 >
(SL,SW,PW): < 1,5,16 > < 1,7,16 > < 3,5,16 > < 3,7,16 >
(SL,PL,PW): < 1,11,16 > < 1,12,16 > < 3,11,16 > < 3,12,16 >
(SW,PL,PW): < 5,11,16 > < 5,12,16 > < 7,11,16 > < 7,12,16 >
```

Till now I am only able to create combinations for keys.but that includes SL SL also which I dont need and also I need to get the combinations of values which I mensioned earlier.

```
public void GenCombinations(String[] str_arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(str_arr[i] + " ");
    }

    /*COMBINATIONS OF LENGTH ONE*/
    for (int i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(str_arr[i]);
    }        

    /*COMBINATIONS OF LENGTH TWO*/
    for (int i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < str_arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(str_arr[i] + " " + str_arr[j]);
        }
    } 

    /*COMBINATIONS OF LENGTH THREE*/
    for (int i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < str_arr.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < str_arr.length; k++) {
                System.out.println(str_arr[i] + " " + str_arr[j] + " " + str_arr[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

current output

```
SL
SW
PL
PW
SL SL
SL SW
SL PL
SL PW
.
.
.
```

How to reach the desired output to get the **combnations of values along with combination of keys**?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You could either check the index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < str_arr.length; j++) {
    if (i != j) {
      System.out.println(str_arr[i] + " " + str_arr[j]);    
    }               
  }
}
```

, or go for string comparison:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < str_arr.length; j++) {
    if (!str_arr[i].equals(str_arr[j]) {
      System.out.println(str_arr[i] + " " + str_arr[j]);    
    }               
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about initializing `j = i+1` and `k = j+1` ?

```
public void GenCombinations(String[] str_arr){
    /*COMBINATIONS OF LENGTH TWO*/
    for(int i=0;i<str_arr.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<str_arr.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(str_arr[i]+" "+str_arr[j]);                   
        }
    } 

    /*COMBINATIONS OF LENGTH THREE*/
    for(int i=0;i<str_arr.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<str_arr.length;j++)
        {
            for(int k=j+1;k<str_arr.length;k++)
            {  
                System.out.println(str_arr[i]+" "+str_arr[j]+" "+str_arr[k]);                      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: if you want to generate all combinations, you might want to do it recursively

```
private static void GenCombinations(String[] head, String[] tail, int headIndex, int tailIndex) {
    if (headIndex == head.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(head));
        return;
    }
    if (tailIndex >= tail.length)
        return;

    // Either take tail[tailIndex] to head[headIndex]
    head[headIndex] = tail[tailIndex];
    GenCombinations(head, tail, headIndex+1, tailIndex+1);

    // Or don't take it, and try the next element to put in head[headIndex]
    GenCombinations(head, tail, headIndex, tailIndex+1);
}

private static void GenCombinations(String[] str_arr, int num) {
    GenCombinations(new String[num], str_arr, 0, 0);
}

private static void GenCombinations(String[] str_arr) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= str_arr.length; i++)
        GenCombinations(str_arr, i);
}
```

Comment: yes now it is comming in correct manner for keys, But how to generate combinations of its values?

Comment: How do you keep your values? Arrays or lists or something else? You'll need to provide more code.

Comment: Basically, the idea is: instead of printing out the keys, use them to index your values. For instance, with two keys you'll have two arrays of values. Loop them to get all possible combinations.

Comment: values as array.I am reading it from file and storing them to an array

Comment: How to get combination of lengh of 4 if I have more keys. whether I need to loop again? how to generate all automatically?

Comment: The laziest solution is to add more loop. Anyway, if you want all combinations, see the edit.